# JavaScript - get arrays of indexes of same value in the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. For example

```
var tmp = ["A", "B","B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"];
```

how can I get array of index for each possible value from array above using plain JavaScript.

```
var A = [0,3,6,7]; //0,3,6,7 are indexes of "A" from the above array
var B = [1,2,4,5]; //1,2,4,5 are indexes of "B" from the above array
```

Thank you.

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: @ Rajesh I have tried using forEach with push and it was successful but I'm looking for more python-y javascript way to do it.

Comment: SO is a portal to help fellow devs with their problems. Difference between requirement and problem statement is that you have attempted something and have failed. So please add attempt in question.

Comment: @ Rajesh I've seen this as a heuristic search solution for my problem which in the real world, this kind of problem would not have a guild. As I said I was looking for python-y javascript way. If I have provided my solution for "for each", it would have been ruled out in the answer section which I don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate and push the index to the corresponding array.

```js
var A = [],
  B = [];
var tmp = ["A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"];

tmp.forEach(function(v, i) {
  if (v == 'A') A.push(i);
  else B.push(i);
})

console.log(A, B);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

- Instead of creating individual variable for `A` and `B`, you can create map which will hold these values as keys.
- Now loop over array and add index to necessary array.

**Note:** Benefit of using a map is that your logic becomes generic and it will be scalable. So it you add 5 more letters, you dont have to create 5 more variables and update logic

```js
var tmp = ["A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"];

var result = tmp.reduce(function(acc, item, i) {
  acc[item] = acc[item] || [];
  acc[item].push(i);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {};
for(var i=0;i<tmp.length;i++)
{
    if(!x[tmp[i]])
        x[tmp[i]] = [];
    x[tmp[i]].push(i);
}

//x['A'] and x['B'] contains what you're looking for.
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

To find occurrence of each element

```js
var tmp = ["A", "B","B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"];
var arr = [];
var temp = [];
for(let i in tmp){
  var indexes = [];
  if(temp.indexOf(tmp[i]) === -1){
    indexes = tmp.map((e, j) => e === tmp[i] ? j : '').filter(String);
    var obj = {};
    obj[tmp[i]] = indexes;
    arr.push(obj);
    temp.push(tmp[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

```js
var tmp = ["A", "B","B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"];
var arr = [];
var temp = [];
for(let i in tmp){
  var indexes = [];
  if(temp.indexOf(tmp[i]) === -1){
    indexes = tmp.map((e, j) => e === tmp[i] ? j : '').filter(String);
    temp.push(tmp[i]);
    window[tmp[i]] = indexes;
  }
}

console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.